# How to get the styles that will be applied for a given class list in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, css, dom, extjs

I've tried `Ext.DomHelper.createDom` but it creates an object without applying the `document styles` to it. The `Ext.util.CSS.getRules` can get all the rules, but I'd have to manually figure out which styles will be overridden and which'll be applied.

Is there an easy way to get the styles given a class list?

Comment: I saw a similar problem solved in jquery by simply creating a small object (without inserting it to the document) with a class list, then it's possible to get the styles - I'm wondering if ExtJs also can do that. It would be helpful for me and let avoid larger refactoring of legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext JS doesn't provide a way to get all the styles for an element, but you can do it with a bit of plain old javascript after the element has been appended to the `dom`:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var el = Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
        tag: 'div',
        cls: 'foo'
    }),
    styles;

    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        // use getComputedStyle if supported
        styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    } else {
        // fall back to currentStyle for IE8 and below
        styles = el.currentStyle;
    }

    // get a style
    alert(styles.fontSize);

});
```

Of course if you just need to get a specific style, I'd recommnend using the `getStyle()` method of `Ext.Element` because it handles the browser differences for you.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'm just concerned about how it'll work on lower IEs, especially IE6.